# Override jQuery mobile button style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I create project with jQuery mobile and have problem with adding custom button.
For example http://jsfiddle.net/W4LWz/2/

I try add my custom button at any place, but my css style ingore and I see standart jQ mobile button.

My css file include:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #beddef;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #beddef, #a3c4d6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#beddef), to(#a3c4d6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #beddef, #a3c4d6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #beddef, #a3c4d6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #beddef, #a3c4d6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #a3c4d6 #a3c4d6 #002a80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

and add this classes to my button:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="Click me" value="Button" />
```

If i add this class to other alement (,

) work greate.

How me override style for any buttoms?

And I can load my css file after jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css?
And last question: Why my css style ignore if a override jquery mobile classes? Work onli if I add !important for all property in my css.

Answer (score 2):

Before you customize your jQuery Mobile button you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works.
When page is active your input buttons don't exist any more, they are replaced with custom HTML structure made by jQuery Mobile.

It is also called markup enhancement process.

This is how your button looks after jQuery Mobile enhances it:

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="null" data-iconpos="null" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Button</span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="Button" name="Click me" data-inline="true" class="btn btn-primary ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false"/>
</div>
```

New button markup will not inherit old button markup. So you will need to change new button **`CSS`**.

Also when changing new button **`CSS`** you will need to use **`!important`**, you will not be able to override original **`CSS`** without it.

Here's a short example how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/W4LWz/3/

#### CSS:

```
.ui-btn {
    height: 300px !important;
    width: 300px !important;
}
```